# How to use gather in R instead of unite

Tags: r

I'm trying to use gather function, instead of unite to get the output. is it possible to do so?

This is my data:

```
 Description             Temp
     <fctr>                <dbl>

1   location1:48:2018-10-23 -0.9381736      
2   location2:83:2018-01-05 1.1714643       
3   location3:73:2018-11-05 -0.7064954      
4   location4:27:2018-07-26 0.4420571       
5   location5:33:2018-02-03 0.9060360       
6   location6:88:2018-04-27 1.9407284
```

I've used to separate to separate the data by the following command;

```
library(tidyr)
sepData <- separate(data, Description, c("Location",  "ID", "Date"), sep = ":")

Location ID   Date   Temp
<chr>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1   location1   48  2018-10-23  -0.9381736
2   location2   83  2018-01-05  1.1714643
3   location3   73  2018-11-05  -0.7064954
4   location4   27  2018-07-26  0.4420571
5   location5   33  2018-02-03  0.9060360
6   location6   88  2018-04-27  1.9407284
```

Now i want to get the data to its original form, using gather.
please help if possible.

Comment: this it not possible with gather - gather is used to transform from wide to long format and that is not what you wanting to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the `?separate`, it also has an argument `remove` which is by default `TRUE`.  Changing it to `FALSE`, will also return the original column without removing it from the dataset

```
separate(data, Description, c("Location",  "ID", "Date"), sep = ":", remove = FALSE)
#         Description  Location ID       Date       Temp
#1 location1:48:2018-10-23 location1 48 2018-10-23 -0.9381736
#2 location2:83:2018-01-05 location2 83 2018-01-05  1.1714643
#3 location3:73:2018-11-05 location3 73 2018-11-05 -0.7064954
#4 location4:27:2018-07-26 location4 27 2018-07-26  0.4420571
#5 location5:33:2018-02-03 location5 33 2018-02-03  0.9060360
#6 location6:88:2018-04-27 location6 88 2018-04-27  1.9407284
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Description = c("location1:48:2018-10-23", 
 "location2:83:2018-01-05", 
"location3:73:2018-11-05", "location4:27:2018-07-26", "location5:33:2018-02-03", 
"location6:88:2018-04-27"), Temp = c(-0.9381736, 1.1714643, -0.7064954, 
0.4420571, 0.906036, 1.9407284)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use paste

```
togetherDate <- sepData %>% 
 mutate(Description = as.factor(paste(Location, ID, Date, sep = ':'))) %>% 
 select(-Location, -ID, -Date) %>% select(Description, Temp)
```

Should return you the same data.frame as earlier.